# How can I keep data from one dataframe based on its appearance in a second dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, intersect

I have 2 dataframes containing similar data. I know for a fact that data from dataframe 2 appears repeated throughout dataframe 1. I want to extract all the rows from dataframe 1 which have an ID matching one of those seen in dataframe 2.
For example dataframe 1 is about 40,000 rows long with a Protein and ID column:

```
  Protein |    ID|
# 4521     33PB
# 6743     67TR
# 6743     67TR
# 6743     63YH
# 5571     84RW
```

Dataframe 2 is only around 10 rows long with multiple columns of information, but I am only concerned about the ID column. Dataframe 2:

```
Length |  Family      | ID 
# 700      transferase   33PB
# 478      Cytochrome    67TR
# 341      Cytochrome    23FD
# 902      Methyl        00QA
# 554      p450          76LK
```

I am trying to produce a dataframe containing the IDs from dataframe 1 which contain the IDs found in dataframe 2, also to maintain the associated Protein from their row. For example here I would want the output to be:

```
Protein  |  ID
# 4521       33PB
# 6743       67TR
# 6743       67TR
```

I have attempted using `intersect()` using the ID columns however this always returns an empty dataframe, the same goes for `filter()` and when using `%in%`. I have also attempted `if(){}` statements however again these don't return my results. I'm not sure if there's a simple function I could use or whether I should set up a `while()` loop. I haven't got any experience in these though, so wouldn't know where to start.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated with this, I've been stuck on it for hours. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `df1 %>% filter(ID %in% unique(df2$ID))`

Comment: @coffeinjunky thank you so much, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 3):

We could use `inner_join` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    inner_join(df2, by="ID")
```

Output:

```
  Protein   ID Length      Family
1    4521 33PB    700 transferase
2    6743 67TR    478  Cytochrome
3    6743 67TR    478  Cytochrome
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Protein = c(4521L, 6743L, 6743L, 6743L, 5571L), 
ID = c("33PB", "67TR", "67TR", "63YH", "84RW")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Length = c(700L, 478L, 341L, 902L, 554L), Family = c("transferase", 
"Cytochrome", "Cytochrome", "Methyl", "p450"), ID = c("33PB", 
"67TR", "23FD", "00QA", "76LK")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

And just to illustrate my comment:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% filter(ID %in% unique(df2$ID))
#>   Protein   ID
#> 1    4521 33PB
#> 2    6743 67TR
#> 3    6743 67TR
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Using dataframes provided by @TarJae

Answer (score 1):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
 subset(df1, ID %in% df2$ID)
  Protein   ID
1    4521 33PB
2    6743 67TR
3    6743 67TR
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `merge`

```
> merge(df1, df2)
    ID Protein Length      Family
1 33PB    4521    700 transferase
2 67TR    6743    478  Cytochrome
3 67TR    6743    478  Cytochrome
```